# FontAwesome is blocking my page from loading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, lite-server

I linked my fontAwesome to the head of my index.html properly. But whenever I try rending the page with lite Server, the page keeps loading without showing anything including my html text! the page keeps loading saying waiting for font awesome.

is it a problem of liteServer? or it's from font awesome .. any help?

Comment: Please paste your html code here also.

Comment: my webpage is rendering perfectly fine.. it was a problem with lite-server